# Convert stream to a stream on the fly with avconv

Tags: audio-streaming, avconv

I'm trying to convert flv stream to another mp3 or ogg stream. The point is I want to use mp3/ogg stream on HTML5 page, because flv stream can't be played with HTML5. So, I configured avserver.conf:

```
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -

<Feed feed1.ffm>
    File /tmp/feed1.ffm
    FileMaxSize 200K
    ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>

<Stream test1.ogg>
    Feed feed1.ffm
    Format ogg
    AudioBitRate 64
    AudioChannels 1
    AudioSampleRate 44100
    NoVideo
</Stream>

<Stream stat.html>
    ACL allow localhost
    ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Stream>

<Redirect index.html>
    URL http://www.libav.org/
</Redirect>
```

the command I use:

```
avconv -i http://some_stream_service?format=flv -acodec mp3 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

console output:

```
avconv version 9.13-6:9.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on May 10 2014 17:26:31 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[flv @ 0x126e020] max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, flv, from 'http://some_stream_service?format=flv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.87.1
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 31 kb/s
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0: Audio: libmp3lame, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac -> libmp3lame)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
size=    1080kB time=66.14 bitrate= 133.8kbits/s
```

It looks like working, but I keep getting 0 bytes on web page `http://localhost:8090/test1.ogg`. Does anybody have ideas what I'm doing wrong?